# Matplotlib plot of log function looks weird

Tags: python, matplotlib

I expect when i plot the following functions they end up similar in jupyter notebook

```py
n = np.arange(2, 100, 1)
plt.plot(n, np.log(n/n+1))
plt.plot(n, (np.log(n) - np.log(n+1)))
```

but I get this:

[image: non-similar log functions]

What am I missing?

Comment: `log(n/n+1) = log(1+1) = log(2)` so this is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math is wrong `log(n/n+1) != (log(n) - log(n+1))`.

I guess you meant `log(n / (n + 1))`. You forgot the **parentheses**. If you try this, both plots are the same:

```
n = np.arange(2, 100, 1)
plt.plot(n, np.log(n/(n+1)))
plt.plot(n, (np.log(n) - np.log(n+1)))
```

If `log(n/n+1)` (without parentheses) was meant, look at @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment. It provides the correct solution in this case. :)

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? My answer is correct and also accepted (thanks at 17_prime).

Answer (score -1):

You need to change plt.plot(n, np.log(n/n+1)) to plt.plot(n, np.log(n/**(n+1)**)), you are missing a () and that's all.